# Passing data from login controller to parent. Angularjs parent controller doesn't get instantiated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem: When logging into application using accountController, the currentLocation properties get set. However, parent controller doesn't catch that changes. I have suspitions that it is not even instantiated as debugging in chrome hits breakpoint in indexController only after I start Batarang scope inspector.

[indexController.js]

```
app.controller('indexController', ['$scope', 'SessionService', function($scope, SessionService) {
        $scope.currentLocation = SessionService.currentLocation;

        $scope.logout = function() {
            accountService.logOut();
            $location.path('/account/login');
        };
    }
}]);
```

[accountController.js]

```
angular.module('app').controller('accountController', [
    '$scope', '$rootScope', 'accountService', 'SessionService', 'Location', function ($scope, $rootScope, accountService, SessionService, Location) {
    $scope.user = {
        userName: "",
        password: ""
    };

    $scope.login = function() {
        var userData = $scope.user;

        var result = accountService.login(userData);

        result.then(
            function(data) {
                $rootScope.userLoginStatus = "loginSuccess";
                $rootScope.userName = userData.userName;
                $rootScope.system = {};
                Location.query(function(locations) {
                    $rootScope.system.locations = locations;
                    SessionService.currentLocation.id = $rootScope.system.locations[0].id;
                    SessionService.currentLocation.locationName = $rootScope.system.locations[0].locationName;
                    SessionService.userName = userData.userName;
                    $location.path("/");
                });
            });
    };
}
]);
```

[sessionService.js]

```
'use strict';
app.factory('SessionService', ['$rootScope', 'Location', function ($rootScope, Location) {
    var sessionService = {};

    var _currentLocation = { id: 0, locationName: "No location" };


    sessionService.currentLocation = _currentLocation;
    sessionService.userName = "";

    return sessionService;
}]);
```

Here is my view

```
<body ng-controller="indexController">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                    <li class="dropdown" ng-show="locations">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{currentLocation.locationName}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown" ng-show="userLoginStatus">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{userName}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </ul>


<div class="container body-content" ng-view>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is part of my routing:

[app.js]

```
app.config([
    '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            })
            .when('/account/login', {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/account/login.html',
                controller: 'accountController'
            })
            //routes omitted for brevity
            .when('/404', {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/404.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/404'
            });
```

**Indexcontroller doesn't update view model after updating currentLocation in accountController. I have noticed that logout button also doesn't work**

Comment: Where do you see `accountController` being used at all? It isn't in your view.

Comment: It is loaded by routing engine. If you need that view I can paste it but nothing interesting there. Logging works fine, it's the data that is set inside account controller that worries me.

Comment: So it is calling `accountController.login()`, and you are sure `Location.query()` callback is being called, but the results are not showing up in the view dependent on `indexController`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have debugged and checked it in Chrome. The accountController assigns good values, but values returned by indecontroller are wrong

Comment: But when I open up batarang, it suddenly "wakes up" and the breakpoint in indexController gets hit, and the good values are being loaded.

Comment: Breakpoint in `indexController`? There shouldn't be any. It runs once, and later you change stuff from `accountController`. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Is should be, that's why there's question mark in my question. It looks like indexController doesn't get instantiated at application start. What can be the cause?

Comment: OK, and is that view definitely instantiated? When does it get loaded?

Comment: I have added route provider to the post

Comment: You have, thanks, but not one of those has `indexController`. I see `homeController` and `accountController` but not `indexController`

Comment: indexController is defined in html directly as it is main application controller. I also don't know if that's recommended approach.

Comment: I see, so the part above is the main page, and all of the routes go via `ng-view` to that `div` on the bottom. No, that should work fine. Where's `ng-app`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66209/discussion-between-vsmax-and-deitch).